# Docker compose can not start service network not found after restart docker

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose, docker-for-windows

I'm using docker for windows (Version 18.03.0-ce-win59 (16762)) in a windows 10 pro. All the containers run ok after running the command `docker-compose -up -d`. The problem is when I restart the docker service. Then, once restarted, all the containers are stoped and when I run the command `docker-compose start -d` the following error is shown:

```
Error response from daemon: network ccccccccccccc not found
```

I don't know what's happening. When I run the container using `run` and the `--restart=always` option everything works as expected. No error is shown on restart.

This is the docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  service_1:
    image: image1
    restart: always
    build:
      context: C:/ProgramData/Docker/volumes/foo2
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        ENTRY: "1"
    volumes:
      - C:/ProgramData/Docker/volumes/foo1:C:/foo1
      - C:/ProgramData/Docker/volumes/foo2:C:/foo2
  service_2:
    image: image2
    restart: always
    build:
      context: C:/ProgramData/Docker/volumes/foo2
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        ENTRY: "2"
    volumes:
      - C:/ProgramData/Docker/volumes/foo1:C:/foo1
      - C:/ProgramData/Docker/volumes/foo2:C:/foo2
  service_3:
    image: image3
    restart: always
    build:
      context: C:/ProgramData/Docker/volumes/foo2
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        ENTRY: "4"
    volumes:
      - C:/ProgramData/Docker/volumes/foo1:C:/foo1
      - C:/ProgramData/Docker/volumes/foo2:C:/foo2
```

The dockerfiles are like this:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet-framework:3.5

ARG ENTRY
ENV my_env=$ENTRY

WORKDIR C:\\foo2

ENTRYPOINT C:/foo2/app.exe %my_env%
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a possible solution editing the docker-compose.yml file as follows:

```
version: '3'

services:
  cm04:
    image: tnc530_cm04
    networks:
      - test
    privileged: false
    restart: always
    build:
      context: C:/ProgramData/Docker/volumes/adontec/LSV2_Lib/Heidenhain/TNC530
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        ENTRY: "1"
    volumes:
      - C:/ProgramData/Docker/volumes/sqlite:C:/sqlite
      - C:/ProgramData/Docker/volumes/adontec/LSV2_Lib/Heidenhain/TNC530/bin/x86/Release:C:/adontec
  cm06:
    image: tnc620_cm06
    networks:
      - test
    privileged: false
    restart: always
    build:
      context: C:/ProgramData/Docker/volumes/adontec/LSV2_Lib/Heidenhain/TNC620
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        ENTRY: "2"
    volumes:
      - C:/ProgramData/Docker/volumes/sqlite:C:/sqlite
      - C:/ProgramData/Docker/volumes/adontec/LSV2_Lib/Heidenhain/TNC620/bin/x86/Release:C:/adontec
  cm08:
    image: tnc620_cm08
    networks:
      - test
    privileged: false
    restart: always
    build:
      context: C:/ProgramData/Docker/volumes/adontec/LSV2_Lib/Heidenhain/TNC620
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        ENTRY: "4"
    volumes:
      - C:/ProgramData/Docker/volumes/sqlite:C:/sqlite
      - C:/ProgramData/Docker/volumes/adontec/LSV2_Lib/Heidenhain/TNC620/bin/x86/Release:C:/adontec

networks:
  test:
    external:
      name: nat
```

As you can see I created a network called `test` linked with the external network `nat`. Now, when I restart the docker services the containers are started with no errors.

Comment: This GitHub [issue](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/3076) is tracking the same problem. Adding the _networks_ section to the docker-compose fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 22):

The network has changed. I used `docker network prune` command to meet the same problem.Recreate the container would fix the problem. Docker would set up the network again for the new containers.

```
#remove all containers
docker rm $(docker ps -qa)
#or
docker system prune
```

Answer (score 10):

There might be some old container instances which were not removed. Check the instances with

```
docker container ls -a
```

You might get output like this if you have some instances which were not removed

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                   PORTS               NAMES
8b4678e6666b        b4a75a01d539        "/bin/sh -c 'eval `s…"   6 weeks ago         Exited (1) 6 weeks ago                       zealous_allen
ee862a3418f2        1eaaf48e9b42        "/bin/sh -c 'eval `s…"   6 weeks ago         Exited (1) 6 weeks ago                       jolly_torvalds
```

Remove the containers by the container id

```
docker container rm 8b4678e6666b
docker container rm ee862a3418f2
```

Now start your container with docker-compose file
This worked for me. Hope it helps!

Comment: Maybe just [removing the network](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_rm/) could be a softer initial approach?

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can just open your docker app and manually delete the containers. Then run docker-compose up on your terminal. Now it should be working. Go to the port either 9000 or 9001 or whichever port you are using and see if minio is actually running.