# Docker-compose jupyterhub issue

Tags: docker, environment-variables, jupyterhub

I have a docker-compose setup with the following setup:

```
./
+-- .env
+-- docker-compose.yml
+-- jupyterhub/
| +-- Dockerfile
| +-- jupyter-config.py
+-- jupyterlab/
| +-- Dockerfile
+-- reverse-proxy/
+-- traefik.toml
```

I follow the recipe from opendreamkit.org and manage to get the system up and running. However, when I run the command docker-compose down and up again I get the following error:

> *jupyterhub_hub *| [E 2020-03-31 08:28:38.108 JupyterHub user:477] Unhandled error starting tester1's server: The 'ip' trait of a Server
>   instance must be a unicode string, but a value of None  was specified.*

I suspect it* has something to do with the following Message I get when I build the system:

```
WARNING: The DOCKER_NETWORK_NAME variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
```

But I was wondering if anyone could provide with me a workaround or explanation to why this error occur?
Thanks in advance for any help in the matter(during these Corona times)

edit: my file docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  # Configuration for Hub+Proxy
  jupyterhub:
    build: jupyterhub                # Build the container from this folder.
    container_name: jupyterhub_hub   # The service will use this container name.
    volumes:                         # Give access to Docker socket.
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    environment:                     # Env variables passed to the Hub process.
      DOCKER_JUPYTER_IMAGE: jupyterlab_img
      DOCKER_NETWORK_NAME: ${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_default
      HUB_IP: jupyterhub_hub
    labels:                          # Traefik configuration.
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:x.x.x.x"

  # Configuration for reverse proxy
  reverse-proxy:
        image: traefik
        ports:
                - "80:80"
                - "443:443"
                - "8080:8080"
        volumes:
                - ./reverse-proxy/traefik.toml:/etc/traefik/traefik.toml
                - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
                - /etc/certs:/etc/certs

  # Configuration for the single-user servers
  jupyterlab:
    build: jupyterlab
    image: jupyterlab_img
    command: echo

volumes:
  jupyterhub_data:

networks:
  jupyter:
          #  internal:
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could reformat your question so the error messages are split out  from your question - like your example directory structure is.

Comment: The DOCKER_NETWORK_NAME warning you mention looks like an error I've seen in the docker-compose.yml file - can you also post that? (You may need to escape the variable, see https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4189#issuecomment-263458253)

Comment: edited a bit, and thanks for feedback.

Comment: I suspect it's the `environment` block in the config. I get `WARNING: The COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.` if I use the same block in an example, due to the escaping issue I mentioned. I don't know why you're seeing the issue for `DOCKER_NETWORK_NAME` though. I'd also try prefixing env vars with `- ` like in the docs - https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#set-environment-variables-in-containers. That will make it an array instead of an object.

Comment: I found a solution for it. I had to ensure that 'ip' got passed on so I added the following lines in the jupyterhub/jupyterhub_config.py file:

c.DockerSpawner.extra_host_config = { 'network_mode': network_name , 'ip': c.JupyterHub.hub_ip }
c.DockerSpawner.extra_start_kwargs = { 'network_mode': network_name , 'ip': c.JupyterHub.hub_ip }

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer**: take this answer with a *huge* pinch of salt as I am just learning how to run JupyterHub and JupyterLab in Docker containers. And in all fairness to all JupyterHub and Docker and Traefik experts, it is not easy for a beginner to figure out which settings to use.

I had the same problem as the OP, but his solution (in the comment of 2020-04-06) didn't work for me. What *did* work was the following entry in `jupyterhub_config.py`:

```
c.DockerSpawner.remove = True
```

This removes the JupyterLab containers after their users log out of JupyterHub. If they are left to "linger", then the *"Unhandled error starting tester1's server: The 'ip' trait of a Server instance must be a unicode string..."* will occur if the same user logs in again. Don't ask me why. Inspiration came from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64343972/jupyterhub-running-on-docker-docker-spawner-how-to-add-volume).

PS: I used Docker version 19.03.12 in an Ubuntu 20.04.1 host, Traefik Version 2.2, JupyterHub and -Lab Version 1.2.2.

Answer (score 0):

Command `docker-compose down` kill current network. After `docker-compose up -d` new network is being created with same name, but different NetworkID. You can check NetworkID of containers with:

```
docker inspect --format='{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.NetworkID}}{{end}}' CONTAINER_ID
```

I suppose this is the main reason of error:

> The 'ip' trait of a Server instance must be a unicode string, but a value of None was specified

because in order to restart specific user container after `docker-compose down` you can disconnect it from old network, connect to new one:

```
docker network disconnect NETWORK_NAME CONTAINER_ID
docker network connect NETWORK_NAME CONTAINER_ID
```

and finally, you can start this container after logging in JupyterHub web-interface under a specific user, which container got this error.

Indeed, in this situation you can use Laryx Decidua answer to remove containers after `docker-compose down`. Another option is to create an external network like in this accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51476836/12247535

More about this behavior / problem of docker-compose in thread https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/5745